# Массовая отправка сообщений пользователям через Viber API

Tags: php, viber

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, можно ли организовать из сайта массовую рассылку сообщений через Viber API (в пределах до 500 номеров в рассылке). Смотрел сервисы, которые занимаются отправкой - все только от 5 000-10 000 сообщений. Если да, то подскажите куда копать и какая стоимость 1-го сообщения, какие ограничения.

Есть ли готовые решения? (желательно на php)

Только что общался с оператором, то вроде как регистрацию public account пока приостановили....Насколько я понял, можно создать личный кабинет, и если отправлять единичные сообщения через него, то будет отправка с какого-то "левого" номера, а если сразу больше 1000, то показывается реальный номер
отправителя...

То что сообщения платные будут, я это понял. вопрос в том, можно ли отправлять через АПИ (возможно даже через сторонний сервис), сообщения на вайбер и чтобы отображалось либо Альфа имя или реальный номер.

Answer (score 2):

Паблик Аккаунты позволяют отправлять бесплатно сообщения только подписчикам Паблик Аккаунта, но в поле получателя вы не указываете номер телефона, а id подписчика. Для бизнеса Viber предлагает рассылать сервисные сообщения, указывая уже номер телефона получателя, но главный критерий является - отправлять минимум 60 тис. сообщений в месяц.

Сервисы в интернете позволяют рассылать сообщения по номеру телефона, но уже за деньги.

Да, на данный момент, паблик аккаунты запретили создавать кому попало. Сначала разрешали всем создавать паблик аккаунты, только нужно было подать заявку и почти сразу одобряли. Потом запретили и разрешили создавать паблик аккаунты для разработчиков. Сейчас же можно подать [заявку на создание Паблик Аккаунта](http://info.viber.com/en-apply-public-account.html), но шансы одобрения стали ниже.